# Unknown controller type with Moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, ros-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to control the open manipulator on the TB3. I created a Moveit config package and everything works fine until I want to execute the plan on a Gazebo simulated robot. Planning is solved but no controllers are found so execution failed.

When I use `roslaunch open_manipulator_controller open_manipulator_controller.launch use_platform:=false use_moveit:=true`  I can control the Gazebo robot but with my custom Moveit config file, I cannot.

I have `controllers.yaml` and I believe it is loaded correctly because the problem comes from the controller types in the .yaml file.

```
[ERROR] [1629291143.338820460, 1893.061000000]: Unknown controller type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
[ERROR] [1629291143.339038429, 1893.061000000]: Unknown controller type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
[ERROR] [1629291143.339144118, 1893.061000000]: Unknown controller type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
[ERROR] [1629291143.339236787, 1893.061000000]: Unknown controller type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
[ERROR] [1629291143.339306340, 1893.061000000]: Unknown controller type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
```

And the respective `controllers.yaml` is here:

```
controller_list:
  - name: joint1_position
    action_ns: /om_with_tb3
    type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
    default: true
    joints: 
      - joint1

  - name: joint2_position
    action_ns: /om_with_tb3
    type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
    default: true
    joints: 
      - joint2

  - name: joint3_position
    action_ns: /om_with_tb3
    type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
    default: true
    joints: 
      - joint3

  - name: joint4_position
    action_ns: /om_with_tb3
    type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
    default: true
    joints: 
      - joint4

  - name: joint_state_controller
    action_ns: /om_with_tb3
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    default: true
    joints:
      - joint1
      - joint2
      - joint3
      - joint4
```

With a bit of research, I found out that this problem is linked to some missing Moveit controller packages. I tried to install them `sudo apt install ros-melodic-ros-controllers` and `sudo apt install ros-melodic-joint-state-controller` but it looks like I already have them.

Anyone has any ideas why the Moveit config package cannot recognize any controller types?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384611/unknown-controller-type-with-moveit/) by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2021-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2021-08-18**:
did you install gazebo-ros-controllers?

**Comment by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on 2021-08-18**:
it is installed in default as well. `ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-control is already the newest version (2.8.7-1bionic.20210616.200839)`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-18**:
MoveIt "controllers" != `ros_control` controllers.

**Comment by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on 2021-08-18**:
Yes, I am aware of that part. Actually that's why I tried to explain the problem as "Moveit controller" issue. However, similar problem may occur if the `ros_control` is not installed (properly). I just tried to explain that part doesn't look like the issue for my case.

**Comment by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on 2021-08-18**:
I guess the problem is in the controller type. MoveitSimpleController has only FollowJointTrajectory and GripperAction type (I am not sure that part, couldn't find a proper documentation/tutorial) . So I cannot load let say `joint_state_controller/JointStateController` as ros_control supports. I don't know how to solve it...

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2021-08-19**:
I think you want to use a

```
type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
```

**Comment by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on 2021-08-19**:
Yes, `position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` for joints and `joint_state_controller/JointStateController` for the last **joint_state_controller** but the problem is that those ros_control controllers are not supported by Moveit (by `moveitsimplecontrollermanager`). That's my question.

**Comment by [Pratik Somaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/27312/pratik-somaiya/) on 2021-08-19**:
@Gates, you can use `position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` with moveit (or any other `ros_control` controller as long as the controller offers a `FollowJointTrajectory` action service ). You need to use  `type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` in your `controllers.yaml` for `ros_control`. For the moveit `controllers.yaml` you need to use `action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory` and `type: FollowJointTrajectory` for your controller.

Check the minimal example in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think two different `controllers.yaml` files got mixed up (controllers from `ros_control` and Moveit! controllers - check the example below). I am assuming the `controllers.yaml` you posted is part of your `moveit_config` package as the controllers are under the `controllers_list` ns (please, correct me here if I'm wrong here). If that assumption holds true can you try changing the following things?

```
   action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
   type: FollowJointTrajectory
```

If you haven't already, you can check this tutorial from the moveit guide for `controllers.yaml` example for moveit: http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/controller_configuration/controller_configuration_tutorial.html#yaml-configuration

Also, it would be a good idea to confirm that the controllers from `ros_control` are running properly as moveit assumes that the robot offers a `FollowJointTrajectory` (or `GripperCommand` in case of gripper) action service. You can use [service](http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager#Services) or [GUI](http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager#Graphical_tools) from the `controller_manager` to confirm the controller status.

**Minimal example** from `franka_ros`:

- [ros control controllers](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros/blob/melodic-devel/franka_control/config/default_controllers.yaml)

> ```
> position_joint_trajectory_controller:
>   type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
>   joints:
>     - panda_joint1
>     - panda_joint2
>     - panda_joint3
>     - panda_joint4
>     - panda_joint5
>     - panda_joint6
>     - panda_joint7
> ```

- [moveit controllers](https://github.com/ros-planning/panda_moveit_config/blob/melodic-devel/config/panda_controllers.yaml)

> ```
>  controller_list:
>   - name: position_joint_trajectory_controller
>     action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
>     type: FollowJointTrajectory
>     default: true
>     joints:
>       - panda_joint1
>       - panda_joint2
>       - panda_joint3
>       - panda_joint4
>       - panda_joint5
>       - panda_joint6
>       - panda_joint7
> ```

---

Originally posted by [Pratik Somaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/27312/pratik-somaiya/) with karma: 146 on 2021-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-08-20**:
I like to give those yaml files nice, distinctive names since they are so easy to get confused. I usually go with `ros_control_controllers.yaml` and `moveit_controllers.yaml`.

The `ros_control_controllers.yaml` typically defines all of the controllers that are available. There may be gripper controllers, arm controllers, and maybe even mobile base controllers all mixed in.

The `moveit_controllers.yaml` (obviously) tells MoveIt which controllers to hook up with. Typically a JointTrajectoryController but I think MoveIt can also connect with gripper action server controllers.

**Comment by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on 2021-08-27**:
wow, really? That's something I didn't know (and couldn't guess either). I thought that the type *must* match the ROS controller type. ATM I am not in reach to the PC which I had this problem. I cannot check if it solves my problem but this answer looks like it can solve issues for many who are having similar confusion with me. Thank you!

**Comment by [Pratik Somaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/27312/pratik-somaiya/) on 2021-09-08**:
Thanks, @AndyZe! I updated my answer and added that one can use moveit! with the `GripperCommand` service as well. It might help someone.

**Comment by [Pratik Somaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/27312/pratik-somaiya/) on 2021-09-08**:
@Gates no worries! I hope that helped.